# Notification system on app using Firebase

Tags: backend, messaging, notifications

I have to build an app that manages orders between customers who submit the orders and riders who deliver them. Riders work in shifts, so when a customer submits an order, only the riders that are active in that particular shift should recieve a notification.

I chose Firebase as backend for my app, so I'd use cloud firestore, cloud functions, auth and FCM.

My question is: how should I organize my data to achieve what I've mentioned before?

I've already made some options:

1. I have a collections for shifts, where all riders active in that shift are recorded. When an order is submitted, then i query all the riders active in that shift (queried by time) and then send a notification to each one.
2. I have a message topic where active riders are subscribed, and then i post the notification there.

Option #1 seems too cumbersome for me. There are a lot of queries to do. Option #2 doesn't need a query at all, but how should i handle riders subscriptions to it (to be more precise, how can active riders in that shift subscribe to the topic) ?

Comment: I guess the app is not backed by a proprietary backend. Right? The interaction is app <-> Firebase. Do you track raiders' state? I mean, when they are active and available to pick the next job (delivery)?

Comment: Yes, you hit the point. I only interact with firebase. And yes, when a rider picks a job cannot pick another one until he completes the delivery.

Comment: Are these shifts always the same? I mean could you create topics per shift?

Comment: Well, for each day shift are quite the same. For instance, a day could be split in 4-hours shifts. The problem is that my sakeholders want to be able to customize shifts. In particular, they want that every week, riders have to pre-subscribe to the shifts of the next week, so that they know who is warking in each shift a week before. I don't know if I was clear.

Comment: This pre-subscription happens at the end of the current shift? Anytime between the current date and the starting date of the next shift?

Comment: The stakeholders decide when subscriptons are open, and then they are kept open until all shifts are full.

Comment: so the stakeholders decide. It's rather an assignment than a subscription.

Comment: Not really, because riders are free to choose whatever shift they like. But sometimes, stakeholders could assign them to a particular one. Also, a rider can choose to not subscribe to any shift for that particular shift.